How do I format the data in an Excel spreadsheet?
There is a file with an **Excel ** spreadsheet containing the following type of data:
россия, московская область, ленинский район, г.видное, ул.заводская, д.6, кв.22 
643,163000,78,,санктпетербург г,,офицерский пер,8б,,5 
646602, россия, омская обл. , горьковский р-н, с. астыровка, ул. комсомольская, д. 17, кв. 1 
656000, россия, г. барнаул, ул. эмилии алексеевой, д. 6, кв. 108

From such data, after passing through the program, you should get the following:
г. Видное, ул. Заводская, д.6, кв. 22 
г. Санкт-Петербург, пер. Офицерский, д. 8Б, кв. 5 
с. Астыровка, ул. Комсомольская, д. 17, кв. 1 
г. Барнаул, ул. Эмилии Алексеевой, д. 6, кв. 108

I can't imagine how to solve this, maybe there are some ready-made solutions in Excel or libraries in Python?
My attempt to write in Python (the result is 50/50):
def parse_address(address):
    pattern = r'(?P<postal_code>\d{6})?,?\s*(?P<country>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<region>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<district>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<locality>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<street>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<house>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<apartment>[^,]*)'

    # Убираем лишние пробелы и запятые
    address = re.sub(r'\s*,\s*', ',', address)
    address = re.sub(r',+', ',', address)
    address = address.strip(', ')

    match = re.match(pattern, address)

    if match:
        address_dict = match.groupdict()
        address_dict = {k: v.strip() if v else "Не указано" for k, v in address_dict.items()}
        return address_dict
    else:
        return None


addresses = [
    "россия, московская область, ленинский район, г.видное, ул.заводская, д.6, кв.22",
    "643,163000,78,,санктпетербург г,,офицерский пер,8б,,5",
    "646602, россия, омская обл. , горьковский р-н, с. астыровка, ул. комсомольская, д. 17, кв. 1",
    "656000, россия, г. барнаул, ул. эмилии алексеевой, д. 6, кв. 108"
]

for address in addresses:
    parsed_address = parse_address(address)
    if parsed_address:
        print("Распарсенный адрес:")
        for key, value in parsed_address.items():
            print(f"{key}: {value}")
    else:
        print("Не удалось распарсить адрес:", address)


Can you explain the logic of what you want to do? Assuming this is a CVS, do you always want to keep the last 4 columns? Is the fact that санктпетербург becomes Санкт-Петербург part of what needs to be done? (I see many other similar changes). Side note: If you are less comfortable in English, you may want to consider asking here
